# asp.net for automated website login testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to login automatically from my site to remote website and this is her link [RoundCube](http://%20https://emailmg.ipage.com/roundcube/)
I stocked in this case about 2 weeks without any result.
note that I use asp.net vb.

Comment: Please show us some code from your attempts.

Comment: 1.The link you provided is dead | 2. You should provide some code that you tried so that we can help | 3. Perhaps read [ask]

Comment: i find this code in the internet but i don't know how can i modify it.

Comment: You might want to look into Selenium for testing. It is versatile and you won't have to worry about cross domain requests. https://dotnetco.de/example-how-to-use-selenium-with-visual-studio-and-visual-basic-net/

Comment: it's works well but the browser prevent me use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim remoteUrl As String = "https://mail.ovh.net/roundcube/"
    Dim firstName As String = "MyName"
    Dim password As String = "MyPass"
    Dim encoding As ASCIIEncoding = New ASCIIEncoding
    Dim data As String = String.Format("FirstName={0}&MyPass={1}", MyName, MyPass)
    Dim bytes() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(data)
    Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(remoteUrl), HttpWebRequest)
    httpRequest.Method = "POST"
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    httpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length()
    Dim stream As Stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    stream.Close()
```

2) this is the remote site link 
https://mail.ovh.net/roundcube/

Comment: `mail.ovh.net` must allow cross domain requests.

Comment: i don't know what are you talking about

Comment: I mean if both the domains are not same (say your application is `abc.com` and you want to login in `mail.ovh.net` by this kind of request, then `mail.ovh` must allow cross domain request. For the security.